# Cassandra Unable to gossip with any seeds

Tags: service, cassandra, datastax

At first I downloaded Cassandra 3.7 and installed it on a remote machine (still in the same network) But I wanted to run this as a service so I downloaded and installed the `DataStax_DDC_Server 3.7.0`

But when I try to connect remotely to the service I get the error: `Unable to gossip with any seeds` 
So i followed a couple solutions to that problem.

[Cassandra Cluster Set up - Unable to gossip with any seeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767605/cassandra-cluster-set-up-unable-to-gossip-with-any-seeds)
[Apache Cassandra: Unable to gossip with any seeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690987/apache-cassandra-unable-to-gossip-with-any-seeds)

I don't think its a firewall or port problem, since I could connect to the other Cassandra database. I also copied the .YAML files from the old Cassandra environment (the one that was working)

What else can I try? Do I have to change more things in the .yaml file in the datastax version instead of the version directly downloaded from http://cassandra.apache.org/download/ ?

Could it be the datastax version uses other ports?

EDIT: It works locally. Also, when i remove the datastax version my old Cassandra environment also works again, but it needs to be a service so I cannot use that environment since it doesn't include a service.

EDIT2: uploaded cassandra.yaml
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wuhwc31oyztotzm/AAC0x9PcH7dIjZszpxRvDNjba?dl=0

Comment: could you please provide cassandra.yaml of all nodes?

Comment: @Sabik Yes i can, i will edit my question.

Comment: in your cassandra.yaml seeds list specified as 127.0.0.1, is it right?

Comment: @Sabik It is indeed specified as 127.0.0.1, should this be different then a localhost ip (service is running on that machine, and thats the only machine running Cassandra) 127.0.0.1 is the default value.

Comment: @sabik altered the seed list, added a host and recipient. This worked. formulate an answer and I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join new node in cluster you should change cassandra.yaml of that one:

1. Specify cluster name (should be the same for all cluster nodes):

   cluster_name: 'MyCluster'
2. Specify seed nodes of cluster (on seed node this own ip or/and other seeds):

seed_provider: 
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider parameters:
 
        - seeds: "seed ip1, seed ip2"

This is main settings for Cassandra cluster