# establish cassandra multi nodes cluster from 3 machines each run single node cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

me and 2 of my friends started to learn Cassandra NOSQL DB , every one of us install Cassandra as a single node in his machine , now we need to connect these 3 single nodes to establish Cassandra cluster with 3 nodes , what is the best idea to do this ? and is there any other requirements?

Comment: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/initialize/initSingleDS.html

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-a-multi-node-cluster-database-with-cassandra-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573480/cassandra-unable-to-gossip-with-any-seeds/39612249#39612249 answer contains the simplest settings example to start